# GridLayout crashes app

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout and I want to alter it with java.
I have the following code:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout1);
GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.rightMargin = 5;
param.topMargin = 5;
gridLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Why does it crash?

Comment: can you upload the crash error log

Answer (score 0):

The type of `LayoutParams` is determined by the **parent of the View**. Unless your `R.id.gridLayout1` is inside another `GridLayout`, you should not be using `GridLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer to mark the question as answered and remove it from the queue. Best of luck in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout1);
        PARENT_LAYOUT.LayoutParams layoutParams = ( PARENT_LAYOUT.LayoutParams) gridLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 5;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 5;
```

and replace PARENT_LAYOUT with the LinearLayout or whatever your are using as Root layout

Comment: Indeed. The error was in line 2 where I should use the PARENT_LAYOUT. Thank you for the reply.